# How to configure Tapestry5, Hibernate, Tomcat7, JNDI, Mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jndi, tapestry

I've been trying to figure out how to configure Tapestry5, Hibernate, Tomcat7, and Mysql, but have not been able to get it to work. Could someone possible tell me what I'm doing wrong?

To began with, Tapestry is already configured to work with hibernate and jetty without issue, I'm having difficulties setting up a connection pool with Tomcat7

What I have thus far.

***MyApp Configuration***

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/rolemanager</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**myapp/Web Pages/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>rolemanager Tapestry 5 Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <!-- The only significant configuration for Tapestry 5, this informs Tapestry
of where to look for pages, components and mixins. -->
        <param-name>tapestry.app-package</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.rolemanager</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>app</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>app</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
       <description>MyDatabase Description</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/rolemanager</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
     </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

***Tomcat Configuration***

**Tomcat7/conf/server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    <Resource name="jdbc/rolemanager" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="root" password="test" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rolemanager"/>

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

**Tomcat7/conf/context.xml**

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/rolemanager" name="jdbc/rolemanager" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

</Context>
```

***Console Error***

I'm getting the following console error.

```
SEVER: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:localhost/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addResourceRef
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be an issue with a dependency in my pom adding conflicting classes. I was able to remove the conflicting classes from my class path and fix resolve my issue.